# Plot a circle and create a 3-D revolution plot out of it

Tags: plotting

If I have the equation `(x-2)^2 + (y-2)^2 == 1` I can use a `ContourPlot`, however am having trouble changing the axes origin. I have tried doing this:

```
Plot[y /. Solve[(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2], {x,0,3}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

However the top and bottom of the circle are slightly separated:
[image]

Also how would I use `RevolutionPlot3D` to plot equation around the Y axis ?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, `Plot[y/.Solve[(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2]==1,{x,0,3}, AspectRatio->Automatic, AxesOrigin->{0,0}]` did not have noticeable separation so I cannot help with that. I also successfully used `ContourPlot` if that works better for you. `ContourPlot[(x - 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -2, 4}, Contours -> {1}]`

If you just need circles, consider looking into `Circle`, `Sphere`, and `Ball`, which are very simple to use with `Graphics`and `Graphics3D`

If you want a sphere with RevolutionPlot3D, I think you will need to plot it one half at a time

```
Show[RevolutionPlot3D[Sqrt[1 - (x)^2], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], 
     RevolutionPlot3D[-Sqrt[1 - (x)^2], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], 
     PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: circle rotated]

I assumed you wanted the non shifted version of the sphere rotated. The shifted version would work the same though:

```
Show[RevolutionPlot3D[Sqrt[1 - (x - 2)^2] + 2, {x, 1, 3}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], 
     RevolutionPlot3D[-Sqrt[1 - (x - 2)^2] + 2, {x, 1, 3}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}],   
     PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: shifted circle rotated]

Comment: Thanks the revolution plot works perfectly. I've added a picture of what happens when I do Plot[y/.Solve[(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2]==1,{x,0,3}, AspectRatio->Automatic, AxesOrigin->{0,0}]. Also ContourPlot does not allow me to change the Axes origin like it does with the plot function.